# Label size depending on container width in CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have 2 rows of labels on all devices (block 2 in image). There are a few requirements:

- First row has 4 labels
- Second row has 5 labels
- The first 3 labels (`Demo Topic Text 1`, `Demo Topic Text` 2, `Demo Topic Text 3`) should be 1.5 times bigger than the last 3 labels (`Demo Topic Text 7`, `Demo Topic Text 8`, `Demo Topic Text 9`).
- Labels `Demo Topic Text 3`, `Demo Topic Text 4` and `Demo Topic Text 5` should be 1.25 times bigger than `Demo Topic Text 7`, `Demo Topic Text 8`, `Demo Topic Text 9.`

I don't know how to fix this for all devices, using CSS/Bootstrap.

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="ho_intro_content">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <div class="ho_in_featured_topics">
              <span class="label huge">Demo Topic Text 1</span>
              <span class="label huge">Demo Topic Text 2</span>
              <span class="label huge">Demo Topic Text 3</span>
              <span class="label large">Demo Topic Text 4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ho_in_featured_topics">
              <span class="label large">Demo Topic Text 5</span>
              <span class="label large">Demo Topic Text 6</span>
              <span class="label medium">Demo Topic Text 7</span>
              <span class="label medium">Demo Topic Text 8</span>
              <span class="label medium">Demo Topic Text 9</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">           
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="ho_in_click_me_button" aria-label="Click me!">Click me!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.ho_in_featured_topics .label {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the base value of `font-size` for the `.label` class.
Then scale based on that value through inheritance. 
To use the initial `font-size` in the document, you may use [rem units](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-values-3-20160929/#rem) such as: `1rem`.

```
.ho_in_featured_topics .label {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.ho_in_featured_topics .label.large {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.ho_in_featured_topics .label.huge {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem: http://i.imgur.com/CMplZhZ.png
The first row should contain the first 4 labels. The second row should contain the last 5 labels... Any idea?

Comment: I tried to change the 16px into another size, but the large and huge labels don't change their size when I change it...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of maths thing. but this is what i came up with.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-primary ">
<div class="row" id="ho_intro_content">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-xs-center">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="ho_in_featured_topics">
          <span class="label huge col-xs-3.1">Demo Topic Text 1</span>
          <span class="label huge col-xs-3.1">Demo Topic Text 2</span>
          <span class="label huge col-xs-3.1">Demo Topic Text 3</span>
          <span class="label large col-xs-2.7">Demo Topic Text 4</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ho_in_featured_topics">
          <span class="label large col-xs-2.7">Demo Topic Text 5</span>
          <span class="label large col-xs-2.7">Demo Topic Text 6</span>
          <span class="label medium col-xs-2.2">Demo Topic Text 7</span>
          <span class="label medium col-xs-2.2">Demo Topic Text 8</span>
          <span class="label medium col-xs-2.2">Demo Topic Text 9</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">           
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  text-xs-center" id="ho_in_click_me_button" aria-label="Click me!">Click me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```